# Wordpress plugin slow queries

Tags: mysql, wordpress

A friend of mine has a wordpress website, pretty much queries visitors only are going so slowly from his plugin.

I understand mysql is for simple jobs but this it is too complex for me, my question is how can I change this query to make it run faster.
And should I put indexes on some fields?

```
SELECT wp_posts . * 
    FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) 
    WHERE 1 = 1
    AND 
    (
        (
            wp_postmeta.meta_key =  'pid'
            AND CAST( wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR ) =  'Marc43'
        )
        AND 
        (
            mt1.meta_key =  'fid'
            AND CAST( mt1.meta_value AS CHAR ) =  '1'
        )
    )
    AND wp_posts.post_type =  'seo_profile'
    AND 
    (
        wp_posts.post_status =  'publish'
    )
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Explain select result:
[image]

Comment: It's not enough info, please run your query with EXPLAIN in front of it (EXPLAIN SELECT ...) and add output to our post.

Comment: I would try to use WordPress functions like https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/ to see if it's slow or not before try to write my own SQL query. If it's still slow, then it might be better to cache the results.

Comment: ive updated my post with EXPLAIN